# Comparing user inputted string to an array variable Java

Tags: java, arrays, comparison

I've included my program below, basically my question is if I input a surname to allow me to find the student I want to delete how can I compare the inputted string to the surname variable in the array?

When I enter the surname and try and compare this to the entries already in the array instead of comparing the surnames it's comparing the inputted string to everything in that instance of it. This is being done in the findStudent method.

I think because i'm passing the entire array here surname contains everything I've entered for that student (surname, forename, exam marks). If I try and just pass the surname parameter i'm getting error messages.

I've searched to see if this was answered already but all I can find is comparing an inputted string to an array that is already defined not an array created from user input.
Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author Connor
 */
public class Student {

    //declare student variables
    private String surname;
    private String forename;
    private int mark1, mark2, mark3;
    private double dblScore;
    private static String course = "French";

    //constructor
    //=========================================================== 
    // 
    // MODULE : Student
    // RETURN TYPE : None 
    // PARAMETERS : args :  String newForename, String newSurname, int newMark1, int newMark2, int newMark3
    // DESCRIPTION : Construct Student object
//============================================================ 
    public Student(String newForename, String newSurname, int newMark1, int newMark2, int newMark3) {

        this.forename = newForename;
        this.surname = newSurname;
        this.mark1 = newMark1;
        this.mark2 = newMark2;
        this.mark3 = newMark3;
        this.dblScore = (this.mark1 + this.mark2 + this.mark3) / 3;

    }

//=========================================================== 
    // 
    // MODULE : getCourse 
    // RETURN TYPE : String course 
    // PARAMETERS : args :  
    // DESCRIPTION : get course name
//============================================================ 
    public static String getCourse() {
        return course;
    }

    //=========================================================== 
    // 
    // MODULE : setCourse
    // RETURN TYPE : course 
    // PARAMETERS : args :  
    // DESCRIPTION : set course name
//============================================================ 
    public static String setCourse(String newCourse) {

        course = newCourse;
        return course;
    }
    //display student details method
    //=========================================================== 
    // 
    // MODULE : displaydetails 
    // RETURN TYPE : None 
    // PARAMETERS : args : [DEFAULT] 
    // DESCRIPTION : write out student details - 
    // name, course and exam marks
//============================================================ 

    public void displaydetails() {

        System.out.println("   ");
        System.out.println("Student details - ");
        System.out.println("Name - " + surname + " " + forename);
        System.out.println("Course - " + course);
        System.out.println("exam scores - " + mark1 + " " + mark2 + " " + mark3);
        System.out.println("Overall score -  " + dblScore);
        System.out.println(" ");

    }


}

class StudentMenu {

    //=========================================================== 
    // 
    // MODULE : add student 
    // RETURN TYPE : None 
    // PARAMETERS : args : studentArray, numStudents 
    // DESCRIPTION : requests user input to add student to array.
    // Upto 6 students can be entered
//============================================================
    public static void addStudent(Student[] studentArray, int numStudents) {

        String newSurname, newForename;
        int newMark1, newMark2, newMark3;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("1. Add a student");
        System.out.println("    ");
        System.out.println("Student surname - ");
        newSurname = input.next();
        input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Student forename - ");
        newForename = input.next();
        input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("First exam mark - ");
        newMark1 = input.nextInt();
        input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Second exam mark - ");
        newMark2 = input.nextInt();
        input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Third exam mark - ");
        newMark3 = input.nextInt();
        input.nextLine();
        studentArray[numStudents] = new Student(newSurname, newForename, newMark1, newMark2, newMark3);
    }

        //=========================================================== 
    // 
    // MODULE : find student 
    // RETURN TYPE : int position 
    // PARAMETERS : args : surname, delSurname, position 
    // DESCRIPTION : finds the position of the selected student
    // in the array
//============================================================
    public static void findStudent(Student[] surname,String delSurname, int position, int totalStudents) {

        int index;

        for (index = 0; index < totalStudents; index++) {
//            if (surname[index].equals(delSurname)) {
            if (surname[index].equals(delSurname)) {
                position = index;
            } else {
                index++;
            }
        }


    }

    //=========================================================== 
    // 
    // MODULE : delete student
    // RETURN TYPE : None 
    // PARAMETERS : args : myClass, position, NUM_STUDENTS 
    // DESCRIPTION : deletes chosen student from array. Moves
    // all other entries down by one
//============================================================
    public static void deleteStudent(Student[] myClass, int position, int NUM_STUDENTS) {

        int index = 0;

        for (index = position + 1; index < NUM_STUDENTS; index++) {
            myClass[index - 1] = myClass[index];
        }

    }

    //=========================================================== 
    // 
    // MODULE : main method
    // RETURN TYPE : None 
    // PARAMETERS : args : myClass, position, NUM_STUDENTS 
    // DESCRIPTION : runs menu program allowing user input
    // to add/modify/delete student information
//============================================================
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //declare scanner
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        //declare variables
        boolean menu = true;
        int option;
        int totalStudents = 0;
        final int NUM_STUDENTS = 6;
        int position = 0;
        String delSurname, newCourse;

        //array
        Student[] myClass;
        myClass = new Student[NUM_STUDENTS];

        //main method
        //menu
        while (menu != false) {
            System.out.println("1. Add a student");
            System.out.println("2. Delete student");
            System.out.println("3. Display all students");
            System.out.println("4. Change course details");
            System.out.println("5. Search for student");
            System.out.println("6. Exit program");

            // enter choice 
            System.out.print("Please enter selection - ");
            option = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println("   ");
            // calling methods using switch
            if ((option > 6) || (option < 1)) {
                System.out.println("Invalid selection made - reenter. Between options 1-6 only.");
            } else {
                switch (option) {
                    case 1:
                        //option 1 - add student
                        addStudent(myClass, totalStudents);
                        totalStudents++;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        //option 2 - delete student
                        System.out.println("Student surname to delete - ");
                        delSurname = input.next();
                        input.nextLine();
                        findStudent(myClass,delSurname, position, totalStudents);
                        if (position >= 0 && position < NUM_STUDENTS) {
                            deleteStudent(myClass, position, NUM_STUDENTS);
                        }
                        totalStudents--;
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        //option 3 - display details
                        Student.getCourse();
                        for (int index = 0; index < totalStudents; index++) {
                            myClass[index].displaydetails();
                        }
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        //option 4 - change course
                        Student.getCourse();
                        System.out.println();
                        System.out.println("Enter new course details - ");
                        newCourse = input.next();
                        input.nextLine();
                        Student.setCourse(newCourse);
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        //option 5 - search for student by name
                        System.out.println("Student surname to display - ");
                        delSurname = input.next();
                        input.nextLine();
                        findStudent(myClass,delSurname, position, totalStudents);
                        if (position >= 0 && position < NUM_STUDENTS) {
                            myClass[position].displaydetails();
                        }
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        //option 6 - exit program
                        menu = false;
                        break;

                }

            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you'll have to check if `surname[index].surname.euqals(delSurname)` because in your `surname` array you have `Student`s and not the strings

Right now your code checks if an instance of the class Student is equal to an instance of the class String, which cannot.

Comment: That's what I was looking for, had a feeling it would be something simple. Thanks